# Moving cube back to its original postion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I use `transform.Translate` on my cube's x and z axis it moves according to pressing keys. But I want the cube to move back slowly to it's original position when user stops pressing keys and default axis are x=0 ,z=0.

```
public float move = 1f;

void Update ()
{
     this.transform.Translate (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") / move, 0f,     Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") / move);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So your best bet is to store the original position

```
private Vector3 _intialPosition;
private float _duration = 0.4f;
private float _startTime;

void Awake()
{
    _initialPosition = transform.position;
}

void Start() {
    _startTime = Time.time;
}
```

And then check if the key has been pressed, and if not, have it move back towards the initial position

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0 || Input.GetAxis("Vertical") != 0) 
    {
        //Logic here to move via arrows...
    }
    else 
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, _initialPosition, (Time.time - _startTime ) / _duration);
    }
}
```

**Unity Documentation**

[Lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)

Comment: this script is attached to cube when i move cube with horizontal and vertical input it moves according to it but i want back to its original position x,y,z =0

Comment: Do you want it to move back when you don't input?

Comment: @TimAllen See where i have the `if` statement in the `Update`? This basically just says, if I am pressing the keys to move, then do this logic, otherwise return over time to that position. Tbh I didn't test this code, however if it doesn't work I can throw into a project

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Vector3.MoveTowards` to slowly move your current transform to a target or original transform position.

```
private Transform original;
public float speed = 0.5f;

void Awake()
{
    original = transform;
}

void Update() {
    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, original.position, step);
}
```

[Unity3d documention - Vector3.MoveTowards](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html)